# Controlling order of evaluation in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm wanting to dynamically make bootstrap columns.

I have the following snippet of code:

```
{% with footer_items=settings.site_settings.SiteSettings.footer_menu_items.all %}
{% with item_len=footer_items|length %}
{% with item_columns=12|divide:item_len %}
    {% for block in footer_items %}
        <div class="col-md-{{ item_columns|maximums:3 }}"></div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

Now, with these 3 `with` statements, it looks pretty ugly, and you can barely understand what it does.

Now I am wondering, can this be trimmed down into the following statement somehow?
(Is it possible to control the control-flow of evaluation in django templates?)

```
{% with footer_items=settings.site_settings.SiteSettings.footer_menu_items.all %}
    {% for block in footer_items %}
        <div class="col-md-{{ (12|divide:(footer_items|length))|maximums:3 }}"></div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```